# How to check that a JCheckBox is checked?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

How can I check if a `JCheckBox` is checked?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the [isSelected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) method.

You can also use an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) so you'll be notified when it's checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 24):

By using `itemStateChanged(ItemListener)` you can track selecting and deselecting checkbox (and do whatever you want based on it):

```
myCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {//checkbox has been selected
            //do something...
        } else {//checkbox has been deselected
            //do something...
        };
    }
});
```

Java Swing [itemStateChanged docu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) should help too. By using `isSelected()` method you can just test if actual is checkbox selected:

```
if(myCheckBox.isSelected()){_do_something_if_selected_}
```