# Evaluating Checkbox Boolean Value

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcheckbox

I'm sure this is a rediculously easy question, but I just can't find the answer to it anywhere. I have a JCheckbox that I need to evaluate the boolean value of, and then change the value with an if statement. The problem is I just can't find the syntax anywhere for evaluating the contents of a JCheckbox, let alone changing it. This will probably be really easy one, but I just can't seem to find anything helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Its inherited from AbstractButton.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599908/how-to-check-that-a-jcheckbox-is-checked) SO thread sort of answers your question. If your `JCheckBox` is named "Foo", you would check its value with

```
Foo.isSelected()
```

To set its value, you would use

```
Foo.setSelected(true)
```

Comment: I don't have a Java compiler handy right now, so I can't say for sure, but I'm pretty sure that just doing Foo.setSelected(true) will update the checkbox to be checked on the form.

Comment: While it works initially in an if statement, any further changes made do not change the other box.

Comment: Never Mind, I foudn the method I was looking for.

Comment: What was it? Future generations might like to know.

Comment: It's the itemListen method. Found it in another question.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean how to check if Checkbox is selected or not, if yes then use [`isSelected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29)

```
boolean isSelected = jCheckBox.isSelected();

if(isSelected ){
   jCheckBox.setSelected(false);
} else {
   jCheckBox.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: add ItemListener to the JCheckBox,

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) from Sun that you can read to complete your knowledge. If you want to know the current selection state of a JCheckbox, just use the method `isSelected()`.