# Replace boolean check-box in a JTable with an image-icon checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Hi I have the same problem that him.

[Trying to replace boolean check-box in a JTable with an image-icon checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963338/java-swing-trying-to-replace-boolean-check-box-in-a-jtable-with-an-image-icon-c)

but I have partly solve doing this:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new CustomBooleanCellRenderer());           
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(new CustomBooleanCellEditor());
```

and works... but I cant center the icon... and I cant update automatically, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, in the renderer and editor, you need to set the `JCheckBox`'s `horizontalAlignment` to `CENTER`

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

    //...

    public CustomCheckBox() {
        //...
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    }
```

(nb- The custom editor and renderer both use the `CustomCheckBox`)

Comment: I'm sure I could create some more (problems) for you ;)