# How to check the state of an JCheckBox?

Tags: java

I'd like to mute my music player `player` using `player.mute()` when the JCheckBox `mutemusic_box` is checked.
If its unchecked and the `player` is muted, the command `player.mute()` should execute. How to get this working? My code currently does not work (may because of the ActionEvent).

The check if it's checked or not is in `actionPerformed`.

```
private JCheckBox pwremember_box, mutemusic_checkbox;

//GUI setup

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if (mutemusic_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("Muted!");
        player.mute();
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Unmuted!");
      player.mute();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am new to java. Feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills. May the issue is in the ActionEvent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check that a JCheckBox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599908/how-to-check-that-a-jcheckbox-is-checked)

Comment: you must `addActionListener` (conatining the `actionPerformed`) to your checkbox, else the GUI would not *know*  that the `actionPerformed` should be called.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer? I do not know how to get this done.

Comment: see Oracle's tutorial [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), these are pretty good to learn the basics and how classes are intended to be used. And here at the right there are at least to links that could help (under **Linked**) ==>

Comment: or just look at [davidxxx' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45402509/85421) below, he just added it  - - - but I still recommend the tutorials!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First this check is not required :

```
if (ae.getSource().equals(mutemusic_box)) {
```

The `ActionListener` should be associated to the `JCheckBox` button.
So, there is not any ambiguity.

Then in order to know if the checkbox is checked, use simply the `isSelected()` method that is designed for.

Besides `mute()` is not a good named method to toggle the sound of the `Player`.
`toggleSound()` could make more sense.

And as explained in my comment, you have to attach first the listener to the JCheckBox.

Here is a sample code :

```
checkBoxMute.addActionListener(
   new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {   
          if (checkBoxMute.isSelected()) {
              System.out.println("Muted!");
              player.toggleSound();
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("Unmuted!");
              player.toggleSound();
          } 
       }
   });
```

And here the same thing with a lambda instead of creating an anonymous class of `ActionListener` :

```
checkBoxMute.addActionListener(
    ae -> {
        if (checkBoxMute.isSelected()) {
          System.out.println("Muted!");
          player.toggleSound();
        } else {
          System.out.println("Unmuted!");
          player.toggleSound();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx for ur idea to rename it. I tried it but nothing is printed in console, also the sound does not mute. Any idea?

Comment: You are welcome. Are you sure to have attached the ActionListener to the checkbox that you select/unselect ?

Comment: Yes. I will update my code and show how `mutemusic_checkbox` looks.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated code :) Now its correct :P

Comment: It was not attached to. I updated. It is very simple.

Comment: @realKSMC You cannot edit a answer to add your own answer in. If you think that adding your code makes sense, add an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isSelected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) method.

```
boolean isChecked = mutemusic_box.isSelected();
```

As a personal advice, rename `mutemusic_box` to `muteMusicCheckBox` or similar.

Comment: Where exactly to use it? :) Thx for the quick respond!

Comment: once you have a reference to a `JCheckBox` you can call it on this object.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am new to java ;)

Comment: @realKSMC here u are

Comment: Noticed your updated answer :) I will change the name, thx for that. I'll try something out and give an respond .

Comment: @realKSMC you can mark this answer as solution by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
mutemusic_box.isSelected();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.